# Waiting for subscription to complete setting a public variable

Tags: javascript, typescript, asynchronous, rxjs

On my component, I get some translations from my service.
The service makes a call to an MVC API controller.

The code on the component:

```
  private getTranslations(): void {
    this._translationService.getTranslations('Foo');
  }
```

The code on the service:

```
  public translations: Translation[] = new Array<Translation>();

  public getTranslations(action: string) {
    this._http.get<Translation[]>(this.baseUrl + action).subscribe(
      (result: Translation[]) => {    
         result.forEach(element => {
            this.translations.push(element);
         });
      },
      (error: any) => this._loggerService.logError(error)
    );
  }
```

In the service, it sets a value on the variable `this.translations` in a subscription.
How can I wait in my component for this to "complete" meaning that the public variable `this.translations` is set?

I saw a thread to wrap it in a `new Promise()` but I wasn't able to figure it out in my example. Any method can be used.

Comment: Return an observable and subscribe to it? You don't have to subscribe inside the service. Or use a pattern that exposes the result/completion separately; see e.g. https://blog.jonrshar.pe/2017/Apr/09/async-angular-data.html.

Comment: One way is to use the `pipe` method on observable with `finlalize` method like `some_observable.pipe(finalize(() => {/*callback method body*/})).subscribe(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can return an `observable` from your service:

```
 public translations: Translation[] = new Array<Translation>();

 public getTranslations(action: string) {
    return new Observable((observer) => { // <-- return an observable
      this._http.get<Translation[]>(this.baseUrl + action).subscribe(
        (result: Translation[]) => {    
           result.forEach(element => {
              this.translations.push(element);
           });

           observer.complete(); // <-- indicate success
        },
        (error: any) => {
          this._loggerService.logError(error);
          observer.error(error); // <-- indicate error
        }
      );
    });
  }
```

and subscribe in the component:

```
  private getTranslations(): void {
    this._translationService.getTranslations('Foo').subscribe({
      error: () => { /* handle error */ },
      complete: () => { /* handle complete */ },
    });
  }
```